# Twitter And Facebook Integration Missing In Notification center?

Tags: macos, sharing, facebook, twitter, notifications

I have recently installed Mountain Lion and noticed that 'Sharing' via Facbook and Twitter are missing!

I have checked the *System Preferences* to enable this feature but I am stuck. Can anyone help me?

Comment: i re-connect twitter accout (delete and create in Mail, Contacs & Calendar), restart mac. Nothing help

Answer (score 11):

The Facebook integration wasn't available when this question was asked - it was added in [OS X 10.8.2](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5460) in September 2012.

To activate Twitter and Facebook sharing, you must first configure at least one Twitter and / or Facebook account via `System Preferences -> Mail, Contacts & Calendars -> Add Account -> Twitter (or Facebook)`. Once you've successfully added a Twitter account, the Twitter widget should appear at the top of Notification Center.

Answer (score 3):

For twitter:

Go to your `system preferences`, type in `twitter`

you should get a drop down menu called `Set up a Twitter account`:

[image: System Preferences]

click on `Set up a Twitter account` and you should be taken to a screen where you can enter your twitter details

now for Facebook you'll have to wait to the fall of this year (2012) since apple will add this feature later. ( or if you have a OSX developer account you could get early access to the beta version )

note: you also can setup 'share' accounts for `vimeo` and `flickr`:
[image: twitter, vimeo, flickr]

Comment: When taking screenshot, i suggest you try using the space bar after having press command shift 4, try it

Comment: actually I now use a program named skitch which works even better!

Comment: I wouldn't say so lol, try the trick i said. No need for manual cross hair selection

Comment: well with skitch you don't even have to press the space bar just click the window you want a screenshot off. but lets keep this off the discussion board here. It's a personal preference :)

Comment: Then do that lol, to capture the whole window without back ground :P

Answer (score 0):

You MUST Log off and log back on!!! The last thing you must do for Twitter to show up in the Notification Center is to log off and log back on to your Account - then and only then will Twitter show up.

Comment: Far be it from me to contradict a statement emphasized by *three* exclamation points, but... I'm pretty sure I didn't need to do this.